# random blank cell in lower left of report ssdt visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-data-tools

I have a random cell on the bottom row (Total row). I had to add a column to the report in order to sort it. I think the random blank cell is from that... any idea how I can remove it?

apparently I can't post an image until I get 10 reputation.  It let me load them and then it tells me this?

Answer (score 1):

r-click cell in design mode. textbox properties. hide.